# My Character slides off the screen despite being repositioned and I am not sure why

Tags: lua, collision-detection, coronasdk, physics

I am creating a 2d game using Corona to practice coding, and I am stuck on a problem. The back of one of the enemies in the game, is shaped like a bumpy slide(sort of), when my character hits the enemy on its back, it begins to slide off of the screen. When an enemy is hit, the game switches to another screen and switches back.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGoZ1jEG0YA&feature=youtu.be

This is a video that shows what is happening, at around 40 or 45 seconds you will see the character begin to slide.

I have tried multiple things to fix this, both the bounce factor of the enemies and player is set to zero. I tried setting the linearVelocity of the player's x coordinate to zero, but that did not work. This is my code for collision detection.

```
  function spawnEnemies()
        temp = math.random(1, 4)
            enemy = display.newSprite(beetle, beetleSequenceData)
            enemy.x = _R + 100
            enemy.y = _CY
            enemy.hasBeenScored = false
            physics.addBody(enemy, "dynamic", physicsData:get("beetle"))
            enemy.xScale = -1
            enemy.id = "enemy"
            enemy.isFixedRotation = true
            enemy:play()
            group:insert(enemy)

            enemy2 = display.newSprite(vulture, vultureSequenceData)
            enemy2.x = _R + 100
            enemy2.y = _CY - (enemy2.height * 0.25)
            enemy2.hasBeenScored = false
            physics.addBody(enemy2, "dynamic", physicsData:get("vulture"))
            enemy2.xScale = -1
            enemy2.gravityScale = -0.01
            enemy2.id = "enemy2"
            enemy2.isFixedRotation = true
            enemy2:play()
            specialGroup:insert(enemy2)

            enemy3 = display.newSprite(scorpion, scorpionSequenceData)
            enemy3.x = _R + 100
            enemy3.y = _CY
            enemy3.hasBeenScored = false
            physics.addBody(enemy3, "dynamic", physicsData:get("scorpion"))
            enemy3.xScale = -1
            enemy3.id = "enemy3"
            enemy3.isFixedRotation = true
            enemy3:play()
            group:insert(enemy3)

            enemy4 = display.newSprite(bee, beeSequenceData)
            enemy4.x = _R + 100
            enemy4.y = _CY - (enemy4.height * 0.25)
            enemy4.hasBeenScored = false
            physics.addBody(enemy4, "dynamic", floatingEnemies:get("bee"))
            enemy4.xScale = -1
            enemy4.gravityScale = -0.01
            enemy4.id = "enemy4"
            enemy4.isFixedRotation = true
            enemy4:play()
            specialGroup:insert(enemy4)

          if temp == 1 then
              enemy2:removeSelf()
              enemy3:removeSelf()
              enemy4:removeSelf()
          elseif temp == 2 then
              enemy:removeSelf()
              enemy3:removeSelf()
              enemy4:removeSelf()
          elseif temp == 3 then
              enemy:removeSelf()
              enemy2:removeSelf()
              enemy4:removeSelf()
          else
              enemy:removeSelf()
              enemy2:removeSelf()
              enemy3:removeSelf()
          end
    end

    function moveEnemies()
        for a = group.numChildren, 1, -1 do
            if group[a].x < 100 then
                if group[a].hasBeenScored == false then
                    updateScore()
                    group[a].hasBeenScored = true
                end
            end
            if group[a].x > _L - 100 then
               group[a].x = group[a].x - 8
            else
               group:remove(group[a])
            end
        end
        for b = specialGroup.numChildren, 1, -1 do
            if specialGroup[b].x < 100 then
                if specialGroup[b].hasBeenScored == false then
                    specialUpdateScore()
                    specialGroup[b].hasBeenScored = true
                end
            end
            if specialGroup[b].x > _L - 100 then
               specialGroup[b].x = specialGroup[b].x - 8
            else
               specialGroup:remove(specialGroup[b])
            end
        end
    end

function onCollision(event)
       local function removeOnPlayerHit(obj1, obj2)
           if(obj1 ~= nil and obj1.id == "enemy") then
              display.remove(obj1)
           end
           if(obj2 ~= nil and obj2.id == "enemy") then
              display.remove(obj2)
           end
           if(obj1 ~= nil and obj1.id == "enemy2") then
              display.remove(obj1)
           end
           if(obj2 ~= nil and obj2.id == "enemy2") then
              display.remove(obj2)
           end
           if(obj1 ~= nil and obj1.id == "enemy3") then
              display.remove(obj1)
           end
           if(obj2 ~= nil and obj2.id == "enemy3") then
              display.remove(obj2)
           end
           if(obj1 ~= nil and obj1.id == "enemy4") then
              display.remove(obj1)
           end
           if(obj2 ~= nil and obj2.id == "enemy4") then
              display.remove(obj2)
           end
       end

       local function showPlayerHit()
           local tmr_onPlayerHit = timer.performWithDelay(1, playerHit, 1)
       end

       if event.phase == "began" then
           if((event.object1.id == "enemy" or event.object1.id == "enemy2" or event.object1.id == "enemy3" or event.object1.id == "enemy4") and event.object2.id == "character") then
               showPlayerHit()
               removeOnPlayerHit(event.object1, nil)
           elseif(event.object1.id == "character" and (event.object2.id == "enemy" or  event.object2.id == "enemy2" or event.object2.id == "enemy3" or event.object2.id == "enemy4")) then
               showPlayerHit()
               removeOnPlayerHit(nil, event.object2)
           end
       end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just simplified the code for you

```
-- utility function
function isInArray(a, s, t)
    local g = {}
    for k, v in pairs(a) do
        if t then
            if v ~= s then
                table.insert(g, v)
            end
        else
            if v == s then
                return true
            end
        end
    end
    return t and (#g > 0 and g or false) or false
end

-- this will hold all the enemies names
local enemies = {}
-- this function creates all the enemies
function createEnemies(name, number)
    for i = 1, number do
        table.insert(enemies, i, name..i)
    end
end

-- now lets create the enemies, 4 enemies in total with the name enemy+n
-- e.g. enemy1, enemy2 etc.. for value of number
createEnemies('enemy', 4)


function onCollision(event)
    local function removeOnPlayerHit(obj1, obj2)
        -- see if either of the arguments are nil
        local objects = isInArray({obj1, obj2}, nil, true)  
        -- now check if objects contains any of the objects
        if next(objects) then
            -- if it does cycle through them
            for i = 1, #objects do
                -- now check against all the enemies
                if isInArray(enemies, objects[i].id) then
                    -- now remove the objects 
                    display.remove(objecta[i])
                end
            end
        end
    end

    local function showPlayerHit()
        local tmr_onPlayerHit = timer.performWithDelay(1, playerHit, 1)
    end
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if isInArray(enemies, event.object1.id) and event.object2.id == "character" then
            showPlayerHit()
            removeOnPlayerHit(event.object1, nil)
        elseif isInArray(enemies, event.object2.id) and event.object1.id == "character" then
            showPlayerHit()
            removeOnPlayerHit(nil, event.object2)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The above script I re-wrote can be simplified more, however I didn't want to change the logic you were shooting for :p

Comment: Thank you but, do you think you could help me with this collision problem?

Comment: I have updated the code to show how I spawn the enemies also I have a scoring system which gives the user points when an object reaches an x coordinate. Can this be simplified to fit my needs?

Comment: @alexjr Are you even writing this code or are you just copy and pasting?